# How to define listeners for Ext.Msg?

Tags: events, extjs, listener

I have defined some listeners on Ext.Msg but they never get fired. Is there something I am missing.

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title:'Save Changes?',
    message: 'You are closing a tab that has unsaved changes. Would you like to save your changes?',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
    icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
    defaultListenerScope: true,
    fn: function(btn) {
        if (btn === 'yes') {
            console.log('Yes pressed');
        } else if (btn === 'no') {
            console.log('No pressed');
        } else {
            console.log('Cancel pressed');
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        activate: function(mb){
            console.log('Height: '+mb.getHeight()+' Width: '+mb.getWidth());
        },
        afterrender: function(mb){
            console.log('Height: '+mb.getHeight()+' Width: '+mb.getWidth());
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching listeners config on `show()` which is a method of `Ext.MessageBox` it dont have any config such as listeners. You can attach listeners on MessageBox and then use show() method to display a messagebox. Below is the snippet which shows the behaviour.

```
var myMsg = Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox', {        
   listeners: {
      activate: function(mb){
          console.log('Height: '+mb.getHeight()+' Width: '+mb.getWidth());
      },
      afterrender: function(mb){
          console.log('Height: '+mb.getHeight()+' Width: '+mb.getWidth());
      } 
   }
});

myMsg.show();
```

You can find the working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30sf)